# I am unable to make express.static() work for me

Tags: node.js, express

Though I am not new to node or express,(which makes it more frustrating), but this time I am unable to make express.static work for me. Following is my directory structure.

```
├── node_modules
│   ├── accepts
│   │   ├── HISTORY.md
│   │   ├── LICENSE
.
.
.
.
├── favicon.ico
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── mynode.js
└── stk
    ├── img
    │   ├── img1.jpg
    │   └── img2.jpg
    ├── index.html
    └── index2.html
```

This is my js file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxxxxxx/privkey.pem","utf8");
  var certificate = fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxxxxxx/fullchain.pem","utf8");
  var credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate };
  var server = https.createServer(credentials, app);


app.use(express.static('stk'));
server.listen(8080);

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/stk/index.html");
});
```

And this in my index.html markup

```
 <div style="width:200px; height:200px; overflow: hidden;">
    <img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="image1">
     </div>   
     <a href="index2.html">index2</a>
```

I am unable to load img1.jpg in my html page. Neither can I navigate to index2.html.
**Strangely enough if I put img folder and index2.html in top level as well as in stk folder, only then I can load img1.jpg in my index.html and navigate to index2.html. This means I have to put these files in two places(top level and also in stk folder).**
I tried

```
app.use(express.static('stk'));
```

and this

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/stk'));
```

but nothing seems to working.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two different routes for stk. You can create only one.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxxxxxx/privkey.pem","utf8");
  var certificate = fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxxxxxx/fullchain.pem","utf8");
const credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate };
  var server = https.createServer(credentials, app);


app.use(express.static('stk'));

// now you should be able to call;
// localhost:8080/img/img1.png
// localhost:8080/img/img2.png
// localhost:8080/index.html

server.listen(8080);
```

In your html it is good call your assets with `/`

```
<img src="/img/img1.jpg" alt="image1">
<a href="/index2.html">index2</a>
```

Comment: I tried as you said by removing < app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/stk/index.html");
}); > but unfortunately it is still not working  (:  .

Comment: @Zeni so if you open localhost:8080/img/img2.png what happen?

Comment: Files are on headless ubuntu server in AWS ec2. But if I open https://myurl.com/img/img1.jpg, I get 404.

Answer (score 0):

Please use it as following, should solve your problem. Before that say **npm install ejs --save**

```
var path = require('path');

//set up view engine 
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'stk'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'stk')));

app.get('/index', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.html');
});
```

& in index.html, please use it this way:

```
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; overflow: hidden;">
   <img src="/img/img1.jpg" alt="image1">
</div>
```

Comment: Though I think path.join and "+" give same results but I tried your method l without success.

Comment: @Zeni Okay, I have edited my code, Please try. Works at my end.

Comment: @Zeni First thing zeni, I think you didn't understand the concept of relative path then. When you put files in stk folder & you're loading index file, which is already in stk, program then knows that you're looking for img/img.png which must be in stk only & so it loads it. you keep files anywhere in structure, point is you should properly be giving path to it.

Comment: & btw, your code also works, while asking questions you should put code that is not working & in proper language. There is so ambiguity in the question. It misleads people.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to solve the problem. @hurricane directed me in right direction, indeed it was problem of routing, but only in nginx settings. I have more then one websites on same server, and problem  was with "server_name" directive. After correcting it everything is now working as expected.
@Tejas Bramhecha I posted simplest possible code, and I said "It is not working for me". That means I know it is very basic code but I wanted some guidance what else could be the  problem. Thankfully @hurricane guided me in right direction. If you can't understand this simple language, and got so confused with the question that you started down voting, I cannot do anything about it but to feel and say sorry to you:).